# А может причастие с зависимыми не образовывать оборота? Обособляемого?

Tags: пунктуация, причастный-оборот

Ужасно не хочется запятой между *единственный* и *сохранивший*, - можно ль избежать?

> А ещё в путеводителях пишут, что храм Минервы – единственный
>   готический в Риме, но это не совсем так. Впрочем, правда в том, что он
>   действительно *единственный сохранивший* – несмотря на многие
>   поновления последующих эпох – свой *готический дух.*

(Курсив авторский.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В качестве варианта:

А ещё в путеводителях пишут, что храм Минервы – единственный готический в Риме, но это не совсем так. *Впрочем, правда в том, что он **действительно единственный из всех** – несмотря на многие поновления последующих эпох –  **сохранил свой готический дух.***